# Jasmine test : Showing variables of angularjs controllers as undefined in test

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am not able to get variable in test case it is showing undefined in test case.
Controller:

```
   $scope.sample = function(){
      var id="151201";
      });
```

Test:

```
var ctrl, scope, ;

  beforeEach(inject(
    function($controller, $rootScope){
 scope = $rootScope.$new();
      scope.$digest();
  ctrl = $controller('controller', {
        $scope:scope
      });
  describe('scope functions', function() {
    it('sample', function() {
        expect(id).toBe('151201')
    });
});
```

Getting an error :**Expecting undefined to be 151201**

Answer (score 2):

1) call `$scope.digest()` in the test itself not prior initializing the controller. digest usually calls the watchers and since you haven't initialized the controller and created the $scope.id then there is no point of running digest prior that. Even within the controller I doubt that you have an event that changes the value since there are no other services ($http) that are use.

2) if you have a controller within you have `$scope.id = "test"`, all you need to test it is:

```
 expect($scope.id).toEqual("test");
```

P.S. $scope.sample = function(){ var id = "12321321"} you cannot that that. First because *id* variable is private for sample function. You don't assign it neither to *$scope* nor to *this*. The other thing is that probably you wanted to assign it to $scope so in this way it will be:

```
$scope.sample = function(){
   $scope.id = "12345";
}

#the test will look like 

it('should assign id', function(){
  $scope.sample();     

  expect($scope.id).toEqual("12345");
})
```

And remove the

```
$digest()
```

call in the beforeEach statement.

Answer (score 0):

in your test id is undefined, you'll need to get the controller's scope's id.

try

`expect(ctrl.$scope.id).toBe('151201')`

or just console.log(ctrl) and look for scope. maybe it's not $scope but only scope.

EDIT:

`expect($scope.id).toBe('151201')`

should also pass your test.